# Jquery Datepicker using .data().datepicker.drawMonth calendar jumps a year if the first month shown is december

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, calendar

Jquery Datepicker using .data().datepicker.drawMonth calendar jumps a year if the first month shown is december and you select a date in January or February.

Datepicker options

```
numberOfMonths: 3,
onSelect: function( selectedDate) { 
            var drawMonth = $('#search_dates').data().datepicker.drawMonth; 
            workers.fn.setRange( selectedDate, this ); 
            var dmindate = $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate');
            var dmaxdate = $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'maxDate');
            if(dmindate != selectedDate) {
                console.log( 'before:' + dmindate + ' - ' + dmaxdate);
                if(dmindate == '0d') {  $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate', selectedDate );} else { $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'maxDate', selectedDate );} 
            dmindate = $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate');
            dmaxdate = $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'maxDate');
                console.log( 'after: ' + dmindate + ' - ' + dmaxdate);              
            }
             $( '#search_dates' ).data().datepicker.drawMonth = drawMonth; // <-- this is new
             $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker("refresh");
          }
```

If the current date is in December 2017 the calendar shows December 2017, January 2018 and February 2018

The problem is when the user selects a date in January or February 2018, the calendar display jumps to show December 2018, January 2019 and February 2019.

Does anyone have a solution to this that doesn't involve modifying the datepicker jquery plugin, as it is minified?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can answer my own question now.

The problem was the value of DrawMonth it was set to 11, so when the selectedDate is in January it takes the drawMonth value and justs takes that month number from the selected year, therefore making the calendar show December 2018 to Feb 2019.

The solution was to take 12 from the drawMonth value if it's more than 9 and the selected Month was Jan or Feb.

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) { 
        var drawMonth = $('#search_dates').data().datepicker.drawMonth;
        console.log(drawMonth);
        workers.fn.setRange( selectedDate, this ); 
        var dmindate = $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate');
        var dmaxdate = $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'maxDate');
        if(dmindate != selectedDate) {
            if(dmindate == '0d') {  $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate', selectedDate );} else { $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'maxDate', selectedDate );} 
        dmindate = $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate');
        dmaxdate = $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker( 'option', 'maxDate');
        }
        var start_index = selectedDate.indexOf('-') + 1;
        var selMonth = parseInt(selectedDate.slice(start_index, start_index + 2));
        if(drawMonth > 9 && selMonth < 3) {
            drawMonth = drawMonth - 12;
        }
         $( '#search_dates' ).data().datepicker.drawMonth = drawMonth; // <-- this is new
         $( '#search_dates' ).datepicker("refresh");
}
```